# After Installing .NET SDK 5.0, should I also install .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I'm new to C# programing & i just installed .NET SDK but i'm confused if I should also install .NET Core SDK or should I leave .NET SDK alone. I've tried searching on google & on YouTube but I can't find the answer.

Comment: Welcome to branding. .NET 5 is just rebranded .NET Core -- the sequence is .NET Core 3.0, .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5.0. The .NET 5 SDK is just a newer [edited by admin] version of the .NET Core 3.1 SDK. If you're looking at the older .NET Framework 4.x, you need a "Developer Pack" instead of an SDK, and this is normally installed through Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET 5.0 is the new release of the family. The goal is to merge .NET Framework and .NET Core into one unified platform.

So in short this is a new version of .NET Core, if you just want to start programing in .NET without the need of one version or another you're fine.

You can check with `dotnet --info` the `.NET SDKs installed`

Comment: "*The goal is to merge .NET Framework and .NET Core into one unified platform.*" -- eh, not really. .NET Framework is essentially being abandoned, and hasn't been merged with .NET Core in any way. .NET 5 is simply the next version of .NET Core, rebranded: nothing at all to do with .NET Framework, except the name

Comment: Uh, Winforms? Wpf? Wcf? Things that used to be the differentiating factors between the 2 are now being ported to .NET 5. For all intents and purposes, they are "merging".

Comment: @NPras WinForms, WPF and WCF were already available in .NET Core. They are not new in .NET 5.

Comment: @cremor fair point, I misspoke. I meant ported to. NET core (now 5). Was just trying to convey the fact that when you keep forking and porting features from one to another, you're effectively doing a merge; and that saying "hasn't been merged with .NET Core in any way" isn't entirely accurate.